# Locating Latitude and Longitude of a city using Selenium 3 in Java

Tags: java, selenium, leaflet, geolocation, geospatial

I am automating Webmap operations for which I have to pass a Latitude-Longitude to the Chrome browser so that particular area is clicked.

I understand Selenium 4 has features to use Chrome DevTools to do this operation. But I have to implment this automation only with Selenium 3.12 or 3.14 due to project restrictions.

This is my following code which I tried:

```
 @Test
    public void testLocationClick() {
        int zoomActionCounter = 1;
        while (findElement(By.className("leaflet-control-zoom-in")).isEnabled()) {
            if (zoomActionCounter == 12) {
                break;
            }
            findElement(By.className("leaflet-control-zoom-in")).click();
            zoomActionCounter++;
        }
        ((LocationContext)getDriver()).setLocation(new Location(37.774929, -122.419416, 0));
        getDriver().get(SITE_URL);
     WebElement map = getDriver().findElement(By.className("leaflet-interactive"));
        waitForFewSeconds(1000);
        map.click();
        map.getLocation().getX();
        map.getLocation().getY();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        js.executeScript("window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition=function(success){"+
                "var position = {\"coords\" : {\"latitude\": \"555\",\"longitude\": \"999\"}};"+
                "success(position);}");
}
```

In this code I am not able to achieve the result. Any leads will be helpful.

I have to pass a latitude and longitude coordinates to the test method so that the click event happens in that coorinate location.

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: Also please clarify what exactly error are you getting here and for what code line

Comment: also mention your manual steps that you wanna automate. it's hard to read what you've already written

Comment: I am not having production url of the site page. I am using only the test url which is accessible only inside the intranet.

Comment: The steps I want to achieve is, zoom to the specified coordinate which I am giving in the code and perform a click action in that coordinate. Further steps I can proceed accordingly.